# Flow formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Found ')'

Tags: error, compile-error, invalid

I am also running into the same error The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Found ')'

I am trying to create a formula in a flow.

```
IF ( {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Cornerstone_Support}, "VSS Generic CSSAVES", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Cornerstone_Subscription_Cloud}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Neo}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_SmartFlow}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Other}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", ))))))
```

Comment: Hi, For the Last If condition you have written only for true condition but did not defined Else condition . `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false) `is the syntax for If condition

Comment: Yes, you can never have a , just before a )

Comment: Thank you! This makes complete sense! I missed this detail,

Comment: When building a complex formula, it really helps to review it in a developer's text editor like VS Code or Notepad++ since these will highlight parentheses / braces pairs and make it easier to spot mismatches.

Answer (score 2):

Formulas quickly become a sea of parenthesis. It really helps to indent formulas like you would with code, especially when it comes to issues of mismatched parenthesis.

So instead of

```
IF ( {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Cornerstone_Support}, "VSS Generic CSSAVES", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Cornerstone_Subscription_Cloud}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Neo}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_SmartFlow}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", (IF({!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Other}, "VSS Generic At_Risk", ))))))
```

Break things onto individual lines, and indent as appropriate

```
IF( 
    {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Cornerstone_Support}, 
    "VSS Generic CSSAVES", 
    (IF(
        {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Cornerstone_Subscription_Cloud}, 
        "VSS Generic At_Risk", 
        (IF(
            {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Neo}, 
            "VSS Generic At_Risk", 
            (IF(
                {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_SmartFlow}, 
                "VSS Generic At_Risk", 
                (IF(
                    {!radio_Please_select_a_product} == {!choice_Other}, 
                    "VSS Generic At_Risk",
                    
                ))
            ))
        ))
```

Given this, it's very easy to see a few issues:

- Your final `IF()` is missing its third parameter (the condition, value if true, and value if false are *all always required*)
- Your extra parenthesis around each nested `IF()` are unnecessary, and are leading you to not have enough closing parenthesis

You could fix this by adding `""` or `null` as your else value for the final IF(), and cleaning up those parenthesis, but when you're checking a single field over and over you should start thinking "can I use CASE() here?"

Using CASE(), if possible, will be less to type and be easier to read and maintain. It'd look like this:

```java
/* First argument is the thing you want to check */
CASE({!radio_Please_select_a_product},
    /* Each argument pair after the first is the target value to match */
    /*   followed by the value to return if the match succeeds */
    {!choice_Cornerstone_Support}, "VSS Generic CSSAVES",
    {!choice_Cornerstone_Subscription_Cloud}, "VSS Generic At_Risk",
    /* ...and so on */
    /* The final argument is the default value (if no no matches */
    /*   succeed */,
    null
)
```

The above example is untested